# View is not refreshed after $scope is updated in Firebase promise

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angularjs-scope, promise

I am using Ionic Framework and Firebase is my BaaS.

Controller:

```
.controller('ProfileCtrl', function($scope, AuthService, DatabaseService) {
 console.info('** ProfileCtrl **');
 var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
 $scope.public = {};

 DatabaseService.getUserPublicInfo(user.uid)
 .then(function(infoSnap) {
   infoSnap.forEach(function(item) {
     $scope.public[item.key] = item.val();
   });
 });
})
```

Service:

```
.service('DatabaseService', function($q) {
  this.getUserPublicInfo = function(uid) {
   return firebase.database().ref('/users/'+uid+'/public/').once('value');
  }
}
```

In my HTML view I have the following:

```
<div><h3>{{public.firstname}} {{public.lastname}}</h3></div>
```

No error and when debugging, $scope.public.firstname as the correct value in it but nothing is displayed.
I have a button in my HTML view ; when I click on it, it changes page but just before page switches, I see the firstname appearing. When I go back to my view, the firstname is well displayed.

I tried to wrap getUserPublicInfo in $scope.$apply() in my controller but I get the "$digest already in progress" error...

Please, help, it's driving me crazy !

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used $q to create a promise. By doing the initial Firebase promise is resolved within the Angular scope:

```
this.getUserPublicInfo = function(uid) {
  console.info('getUserPublicInfo - get user public information for uid: '+uid);
var deferred = $q.defer();

  firebase.database().ref('/users/'+uid+'/public/').once('value')
  .then(function(snap) {
    deferred.resolve(snap);
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    deferred.reject(error);
  });

  return deferred.promise;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To resove,  "$digest already in progress" error... put $scope .$appy inside timeout service.

```
DatabaseService.getUserPublicInfo(user.uid)
 .then(function(infoSnap) {
   infoSnap.forEach(function(item) {
     $scope.public[item.key] = item.val();
    $timeout(function(){
        $scope.$apply()
},1)
   });
 });
```

Edit 1: Try this to avoid using `$scope.$apply()`. I haven't tested it. But it should work.

```
DatabaseService.getUserPublicInfo(user.uid)
     .then(function(infoSnap) {
   $scope.updatePublic(infoSnap)
       });
     });


$scope.updatePublic = function (infoSnap) {
    infoSnap.forEach(function(item) {
         $scope.public[item.key] = item.val();
 })
}
```

Comment: Thank you Ved for your quick answer but I would like to avoid having to resolve the $digest error but avoiding to use $apply(). Do you know why my first piece of code isn't working?

Comment: When $scope is updated inside outside Angular world, $digest cycle is not triggered. Same case here. If you wish to avoid use of $appy(), than other option is you must assign value to $scope.public inside Angular world.

Comment: add semicolon properly `$timeout(function(){
        $scope.$apply();
},1);`